# What does TCP recv actually DO?

Tags: tcp

I'm having a hard time figuring the best way to word my question... once you have a TCP socket connection established and you are consuming data sent from another server, what part does `recv` play in this?

My understanding is that once a connection is established, data will "appear" in my client's receive buffer when the remote socket sends it - it doesn't wait for me to *ask* for the data by calling `recv`, the drivers handle this behind the scenes?

So does this mean `recv` (or library implementations e.g `Socket.Receive` in .Net) is simply monitoring the local receive data buffer? It seems it can't be otherwise it wouldn't know the difference between waiting for data, and en error state where the connection is lost.

If local data is already buffered then I believe `recv` does simply operate on this local data, but what does it do when I request data that isn't already buffered?

the [docs for Win32 `recv` say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) "The recv function is used to read incoming data" but it doesn't appear to clarify - does the sender wait for `recv` before sending data from it's send buffer? Or does my receive buffer fill up regardless?
Put another way does `recv`:

1. Say to the remote socket "please send me some data"
2. Check local buffer "do I already have some data"?

The docs also say

> If no incoming data is available at the socket, the recv call blocks
>   and waits for data to arrive according to the blocking rules defined
>   for WSARecv with the MSG_PARTIAL flag not set unless the socket is
>   nonblocking. In this case, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned with
>   the error code set to WSAEWOULDBLOCK. The select, WSAAsyncSelect, or
>   WSAEventSelect functions can be used to determine when more data
>   arrives.

This seems to be the key section but I just don't understand it - it waits for dat to arrive but how can it tell if there is an error simply by waiting?

Comment: Let me know if I can reword this better - it should be clear I'm struggling to explain well because I don't understand exactly what I'm asking, I think.

Comment: Start with reading its manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin so it says "The recv function is used to read incoming data" but it doesn't appear to clarify - does the sender wait for `recv` before sending data from it's send buffer? Or does my receive buffer fill up regardless?

Comment: I did. I didn't find the answer to my question. If you know the answer, please share it! The line I quoted isn't the first sentence...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions simply:

---

> does recv:
>
> 1. Say to the remote socket "please send me some data"
> 2. Check local buffer "do I already have some data"?

It checks a local buffer.

---

> what does it do when I request data that isn't already buffered?

The recv call blocks and waits for data to arrive (or for an error to happen).

---

> it waits for data to arrive but how can it tell if there is an error simply by waiting?

It's job is to simply wait, it's the OS job to fill the buffer with the received bytes, and notify it when data becomes available (or an error happen).